# Function Error Variable Referenced before Assignment

Tags: python

I have seen similar question before, but mostly about defining global variables. I am struggling to understand why I get the following error "local variable 'rank' referenced before assignment". Any comment, suggestion or explanation would be highly appreciate it. Cheers.

```
vrp = np.log(1/vols.div(rv.values))
car = ir.copy()

def func(regime):
    for i in regime:
        if i == 3:
            rank = vrp.shift(1).rank(ascending=False, axis=1)
        else:
            if i == 2:
                rank = car.shift(1).rank(ascending=True, axis=1)
            else:
                if i == 1:
                    rank = vrp.shift(1).rank(ascending=True, axis=1)
    return rank
```

Comment: Let’s imagine that i is never 1, 2, or 3 - now, when does rank get assigned a value before the `return rank`? BTW you can use `elif` instead of nesting further if statements after `else`

Answer (score 0):

When `i` is not any of the `3, 2 or 1`, rank is never assigned a values. So, few things which you can do is

1. assign a default value before the loop
2. have a `else` part without any condition in it like in last part of the code

.

```
if i == 1:
    rank = vrp.shift(1).rank(ascending=True, axis=1)
else:
    rank = `something here`
```

Comment: Welcome! Consider accepting the answer, if it solves your problem